# Trigonometric functions in JPA

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I'm running the following query in JPA:

```
SELECT c, acos(sin(:lat) * sin(c.latitude) + cos(:lat) * cos(c.latitude) * cos(c.longitude - :lng)) as dist FROM Item c JOIN c.dish.dishtags tags WHERE tags IN :tags AND (c.latitude >= :lat1 AND c.latitude <= :lat2) AND (c.longitude >= :lng1 AND c.longitude <= :lng2) AND dist <= :maxdist
```

But I'm getting the following exception:

```
[27, 42] The right expression is not an arithmetic expression.
[45, 98] The right expression is not an arithmetic expression.
[13, 14] The SELECT clause has 'acos' and '(sin(:lat) * sin(c.latitude) + cos(:lat) * cos(c.latitude) * cos(c.longitude - :lng)) AS dist' that are not separated by a comma.
```

I searched a bit and it seems that some people suggest to use native queries when using trigonometric functions, but it would be really annoying to me since I'd have to modify a lot of queries already written in JPA. So I'm asking: is there a way to modify the query to make it work? It would be very strange if the JPA framework does not support common trigonometric functions.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JPQL does NOT support those trig functions (JDO does FWIW). Some implementations may have support for them as vendor extensions. I know that [DataNucleus JPA does](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jpa/jpql.html#functions), but others may too.

Alternatively use JPQL standard, with (long winded) syntax like

```
function('sin', :lat)
```

Though this will potentially throw away database independence, should that be a concern for your project.

Comment: the 'function' keyword seems an interesting option indeed (as for db independence, I think all sql databases have a 'sin' function). I hope that nesting functions won't create problems/performance issues. I will test this and report back. Thanks!

Comment: @splinter123 did the nesting of the functions work? If so, could you share how?